# FCM throws 401 after some time for data message notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending data message notification from Java app server to the FCM rest endpoint. Everything works fine, data messages are received by the app without any issues,  however after some time (without any noticeable trend) ,  FCM stars returning 401. I am using Apache common's HTTPClient library to make the http callss. This is the relevant code snippet

```
final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/proj1/messages:send");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ accessToken);
responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

And this snippet is for getting the access token for API authorization

```
 static{
             FileInputStream refreshToken = null;
             refreshToken = new FileInputStream("C:/prj/proserviceaccoutkey.json");
             googleCredentials=GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken).createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
             options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder() .setCredentials(googleCredentials).build();
    }

// Gets called each time a data message needs to be sent
  public static synchronized String getAccessToken()
    {
        if(googleCredentials.getAccessToken()==null)
            try {
                googleCredentials.refresh();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like googleCredentials.getAccessToken() will always return non-null, even when the cahce token in no longer valid, and this is why token was not getting refreshed in the code. Applied the following fix, and it's working now.

```
public static synchronized String getAccessToken()
    {
        if(googleCredentials!=null)
            try {
                googleCredentials.refresh();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
```

Though, it's not really utilizing the cached token, as every time it will be refreshing the token, but my issue has been rsolved for now.